# Laravel soft delete: model::onlyTrashed() returns all

Tags: laravel, view, controller

When I try to view only soft deleted records in Laravel the onlyTrashed returns all records.

As you will see I also have a searchform which complifies things a bit. And I think the searchform is the reason this doesn't work but I don't understand why excactly.

Controller:

```
    public function toTrashbin(Request $request) {
        $search = '%' . $request->input('search') . '%';
        $students = Student::onlyTrashed()
            ->where('first_name', 'like', $search)
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', $search)
            ->orWhere('rnumber', 'like', $search)
            ->paginate(15)
            ->appends(['search'=> $request->input('search')]);
        return view('admin.students.students_trashbin')->with('students', $students);;
    }
```

View:

```
                    {{--searchform--}}
                    <form method="get" action="/students/trashbin" id="searchForm">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search"
                                       value="{{request()->search}}" placeholder="Search by name or R-number">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2 mb-2">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <hr>

                @if (count($students) > 0)
                    {{--table--}}
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">R-number</th>
                            <th scope="col">Deleted at</th>
                            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($students as $student)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$student->first_name}} {{$student->last_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$student->rnumber}}</td>
                                <td>{{$student->deleted_at}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="/students/{{$student->id}}/restore">restore</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {{$students->links()}} {{--pagination--}}
                @else
                    <p>No students found using your searchquery.</p>
                @endif
```

Somehow the view displays all students, both soft deleted and not soft deleted ones.

However: It works perfectly if I remove the 3 "where"s in the controller. But then I can't use search obviously. Does anyone know how I can make this work with search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by changing the controller to this:

```
    public function toTrashbin(Request $request) {
    $search = '%' . $request->input('search') . '%';
    $conditions = [
        ['first_name', 'like', $search, 'or'],
        ['last_name', 'like', $search, 'or'],
        ['rnumber', 'like', $search, 'or'],
        ];
    $students = Student::onlyTrashed()
        ->where($conditions)
        ->paginate(15)
        ->appends(['search'=> $request->input('search')]);
    return view('admin.students.students_trashbin')->with('students', $students);;
}
```

Honestly still not sure what was wrong with my original controller so if anyone knows the cause, please let me know. But hey, at least I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

On your first try, Laravel did something like this:

```
select * from `students` where `students`.`deletedAt` is not null and `last_name` like 'test' or `last_name` like 'test';
```

On your second approach, the query was mounted like this:

```
select * from `students` where `students`.`deletedAt` is not null and (`last_name` like 'test' or `last_name` like 'test');
```

Be extra careful when using "OR" on SQL because it can mess up your results and "*ignore*" some conditions.

You can control your parentheses doing somethin like this:

```
$search = '%' . $request->input('search') . '%';
$query = Student::onlyTrashed();

$query->where('votes', '>', 100)
      ->orWhere(function($query) use ($search) {
           $query->where('name', $search)
                 ->where('votes', '>', 50);
        });

$query->paginate(15);
```

Extra information on Closures here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Have a good day!